# How to render SVG code contained in object in AngularJS

Tags: html, angularjs, svg, coffeescript

I am currently having trouble generating this svg image via the template HTML of my directive. I am using AngularJS, but it is written in CoffeeScript.

```
  .directive 'FileOutput', () ->

    result =
      restrict: "A"
      replace: true
      transclude: true
      scope: {item: "="}
      template: '<div>' +
                  '<div ng-if = "item.type == \'seg\'">{{item.data}}' +
                  '</div>'
```

The start of the SVG object looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="no"?>
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
<svg width="3000px" height="3000px" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
<g id="bg">
<rect x="0" y="0" width="3000px" height="3000px" style="fill:rgb(255,255,255);"/>
```

The code, so far, checks the incoming **item** object, and checks if **item.type** is equal to 'seg'. This part works fine. The second part of the incoming object is **item.data**, which contains all of the SVG code. The best success I have had so far is display the raw code on the web page currently.

I am not sure how to actually render the image that is contained within this raw code.

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Did you try this?

```
  template: '<div>' +
              '<div ng-if = "item.type == \'seg\'">' + item.data +
              '</div>'
```